# Delete a list in c++

Tags: c++, list, dynamic

I have classes A and B. Class B has a pointer to class A as a field, pointing to a list:

```
 struct A {
      A* next;
      char* txt;
    ...};
struct B {
      A* next;
      int length;
    ...};
```

I make each element of this list in this way:

```
void B::add_elem(char* str) {
  A* tmp;
  tmp = new A;
  tmp->txt = str;
  tmp->next = next;
  next = tmp;
}
```

And I have to delete the list at the end. Will it be deleted by default with a destructor of class A, as I've called `new A`(but I made my destructors to print messages, there were no ones) or should I delete it explicitly (I've tried, it was a mistake in compilation)? Help, please.

```
B::~B() {
  int i;
  A* tmp;
  cout<<"del list\n";
  if (next) { // at least one elem                                                                                                    
    tmp = next;
    while (tmp->next) {
      tmp = tmp->next;
      delete next;
      cout<<"del elem\n";
      next = tmp;
    }
    delete tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: For every `new` you need a `delete`. There is no `delete`in your code, therefore the elements of the list won't be deleted.

Comment: The `new A` only created a single element of your list. To delete all elements you have to walk through your list and to call `delete` for every single element. Also, not to loose your links among elements you have to traverse the list in backwards order in your case as it's only single linked.

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In fact, the structure is a bit more complicated, so if I post all the code it will be hard to understand it. I'll try to follow your advice, thanks.

Comment: @NastyaNirvana that's why you shouldn't post you complete code but an MCVE (M standing for Minimal). And if you get a compiler error, you should include the error in your question as well as the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: As I said in my answer you should figure out who owns which pointer. The way you are deleting them you are implying that B owns all the pointer included in all the As, which is going to complicate matters. If the destructor of A deletes the next pointer it contains and the destructor of B deletes the his own the only think you will have to do is a destructor in each of the class containing 1 line: `delete next`.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of any pointer which is created with `new` must be managed manually by the creator using a matching `delete` to free the memory.

This means that every class owning a raw pointer MUST take care of its deletion. This is usually done in the destructor. If you are using C++11 you can use a unique_ptr instead of a raw pointer which will manages his own lifetime. This will help you get rid of many error and memory leaks but will add a few more constraint to your design. In most cases those constraint are what you would actually want to have.

For a nice treatment of the memory management problems in C++ you can take a look at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it works! It turned out, that I've forgotten to give memory to some field but in the destructor I wanted to delete it. It was a complicated class: some static fields and one dynamic: a dynamic massive, each member of which is a pointer to a list. 
At last, this destructor works:

```
set::~set() {
  int i;
  elem* tmp;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (table[i].next) { // at least one elem                                                                                         
      tmp = table[i].next;
      while (tmp->next) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        delete table[i].next;
        table[i].next = tmp;
      }
      delete tmp;
    }
  }
  delete[] table;
  cout<<"del set\n";
}

nirvana@lpt00:~/cpp/new$ ./a.out 
new set
new list
new list
new list
new list
new list
new el
new el
del el
del el
del list
del list
del list
del list
del list
del set
```

Thanks everyone!